# ManageEngine runs on Apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, manage

What is the web server used by "ManageEngine Firewall Analyzer". When opened and checked with firebug, it is showing "Apache-Coyote/1.1". But the Apache service is not running in Windows service manager or task manager.

If there is no active web server how does this tool running properly?

Answer (score 1):

ManageEngine Firewall Analyzer, has an in-built Apache Tomcat server which is started internally and not as an separate process.